# Why ethereum before the Merge is called execution layer and the Merge is called consensus layer?

Tags: consensus, eth-2.0, the-merge

Doesn't the origin ethereum before the Merge have a consensus layer(the PoW consensus) too? If so, why it's called the execution layer now, and only the Merge is called the execution layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Beacon Chain is the Proof of Stake consensus layer.  Conceptually, the execution chain gets merged with the Beacon Chain:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/ethereum/annotated-spec/blob/master/merge/beacon-chain.md#introduction

Comment: so that's said, the execution chain actually also has its own consensus(PoW), while at the Merge, the execution chain abandons its PoW and adopts the Beacon chain's PoS, so the execution chain is a pure "execution" chain now. Am I understanding right?

Comment: Yes, sounds OK.